# How do I embed a React Native subview in an Android module?

Tags: react-native

I want to do something like this:

```
const MyAndroidModule = requireNativeComponent('MyAndroidModule', null);

<MyAndroidModule
  onChange={this.onBind.bind(this)}
  rowHeight={this.props.rowHeight}>
  <View>
    <Text>This should render inside of the android module.</Text>
  </View>
</MyAndroidModule>
```

I believe in iOS you can use `insertReactSubview()` for this in Objective C.  How would I do this in Android?